# the error in javascript code is: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'owner')

Tags: javascript

i am new to javascript getting error in .owner in the classes
this is the error iam getting when exexcuting

```
var users = await myClassStudents(classes, classes[0].owner);
                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'owner')
```

this is the code structure:

```
async function createXlAttSheet(classes, response,owner,counter) {

    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook()

    let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('attendance_sheet')

    var columns = [
        { header: 'SrNo', key: 'SrNo' },
        { header: 'Rollno', key: 'Rollno', width: 10 },
        { header: 'Name', key: 'Name', width: 15 },
    ]
    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        columns.push({ header: classes[i].name, key: classes[i].name, width: 15 })
    }
    colSize = columns.length;
    worksheet.columns = columns
    var users = await myClassStudents(classes, classes[0].owner);
```

i am expecting to get the solution of the `.owner`

Comment: and where is the key `owner` in that array of objects? what does your `classes` array look like?

Comment: where does `classes` come from?

Comment: my guess is that there is no `owner` key present in `classes` array or classes is probably an object and not an array

Comment: `classes` might be an empty array

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining may hide your error for now!

```
classes[0]?.owner
```